# spliting sigle row of string in form of tuple in list to multiple rows (equal to number of tuple)

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a `DataFrame` which has tuples of strings in one row and its id.

like:

```
id         words
223        [('flying bird','round place'),('blue sky','red rose')]
368        [('fairy tales','great day'),('show time','break free'),('noise free')]
```

I want:

```
id         words
223        [('flying bird','round place')]
223        [('blue sky','red rose')]
368        ['fairy tales','great day')]
368        [('show time','break free')]
368        [('noise free')]]
```

In python pandas dataframe.

Comment: Why? This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/184179).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Last column `words` is converted to `list` of tuples, but if tuple has only one element, you need add `,`:

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df = df.words.apply(pd.Series)
df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index(name='words')

df['words'] = df.words.apply(lambda x: [(x,)] if len(x) > 2 else [x] )
print (df)
    id                         words
0  223  [(flying bird, round place)]
1  223        [(blue sky, red rose)]
2  368    [(fairy tales, great day)]
3  368     [(show time, break free)]
4  368               [(noise free,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'id': [233, 368],
     'words': [[('flying bird','round place'),('blue sky','red rose')],
                [('fairy tales','great day'),('show time','break free'),('noise free')]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
dfidtemp = df['id']
df = df['words'].apply(pd.Series, 1)
df.index = dfidtemp
rslt = df.stack()
```

Wondering if this is what you want:

```
rslt
Out[123]: 
id    
233  0    (flying bird, round place)
     1          (blue sky, red rose)
368  0      (fairy tales, great day)
     1       (show time, break free)
     2                    noise free
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words=[]
ids = []
for i in df.index:
    words = words + df.words[i]
    ids = ids + [df.id[i]]*len(df.words[i])
df = pd.DataFrame({'words':words,'ids':ids})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) `literal_evaluation` to parse `tuples` out of `strings`:

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
df = df.groupby('id')['words'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(make_tuple(x.iloc[0])).apply(lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, tuple) else [(x, )])).to_frame()
```

to get:

```
                              words
id                                 
223 0  [(flying bird, round place)]
    1        [(blue sky, red rose)]
368 0    [(fairy tales, great day)]
    1     [(show time, break free)]
    2               [(noise free,)]
```